# How to calculate kernel code size with vmlinux or bzImage?

Tags: c, linux, shell, assembly

I can calculate kernel code size to use the execution results of following command.

```
cat /proc/iomem
```

But I want to caluculate kernel code size with vmlinux or bzImage.

[about kernel code size]
If kernel code is stored from 0x30000000 to 0x40000000(physical address),
kernel code size is 0x10000000(= 0x40000000 - 0x30000000).

Comment: What do you mean by "code size"?

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/scripts/extract-vmlinux

Comment: if kernel code is stored 0x30000000-0x40000000 , I mean kernel code size is 0x10000000 byte.